# Codeigniter 3 Query Builder not enabled for the configured database. Aborting. Error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I encountered an error while writing the session data to the database environment while performing multi-database operation.
My database config file is as follows;

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session');

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'ip',
    'username' => 'name',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['db2'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => $CI->session->firma_db_ip,
    'username' => $CI->session->firma_db_kullanici,
    'password' => $CI->session->firma_db_sifre,
    'database' => $CI->session->firma_db,
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

and then my code to write session to database in config file is as follows;

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';  // select database driver
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';  // name of the mysql table
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

The error I get is as follows;

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Exception
>
> Message: Query Builder not enabled for the configured database.
> Aborting.
>
> Filename:
> /home/x/domains/x/public_html/x/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 90
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/x/domains/x/public_html/x/application/config/database.php
> Line: 82 Function: library
>
> File: /home/x/domains/x/public_html/x/index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think you are missing the 'auto_init' configuration in the default database.

Comment: Searching for your error shows a few suggestions, did you check those? 
 Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932569/query-builder-not-enabled-for-the-configured-database

Answer (score 1):

Check in autoload.php and ensure that the session library is loaded.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```